# Delete a method using JDT

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I am creating a utility to detect unused methods in a code base. By using the below code i am able to succesfully find the unused methods (having no references) . But i also need to delete such unused methods. Please let me know if it is possible through JDT.

```
// Get all the type declaration of the class.
IType [] typeDeclarationList = unit.getTypes();

for (IType typeDeclaration : typeDeclarationList) {
     // Get methods under each type declaration.
     IMethod [] methodList = typeDeclaration.getMethods();

     for (IMethod method : methodList) {

          final List<String> referenceList = new ArrayList<String>();

          // loop through the methods and check for each method.
          String methodName = method.getElementName();
          if (!method.isConstructor()) {

              // Finds the references of the method and returns the references of the method.
              JDTSearchProvider.searchMethodReference(referenceList, method, scope, iJavaProject);
          }
         if (referenceList.isEmpty()) {
                // delete method
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the Javadoc of IMethod it has a method delete() from ISourceManipulation.

see:

http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IMethod.html

Comment: +1 for the reply. I actually tried IMethod.delete() in my code, but the deletion is not reflected in the actual code.

Comment: i just found out ICompilationUnit.commit method. Seems i have to commit the file after making the change. Will revert back to you after testing the same.

Comment: Got busy in some other work. I used a different approach by extending the ASTVisitor class. Used node.delete() in the Visitor class to delete the method. Used RecordModification to update the JavaClass with the changes. Then did a manual rewrite of the java file.

Answer (score 0):

Usually ASTRewrite is used to modify source. You can take a look at the implementation of 'Remove unused method' quick fix -

> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.fix.UnusedCodeFix.RemoveUnusedMemberOperation.removeUnusedName(CompilationUnitRewrite,
>   SimpleName)

You can also just use the Clean-Up from JDT to do this, see 'Source > Clean up > Unnecessary Code > Remove unused private members'